# Displaying Text When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In this project, my aim is to change emoji when I click and also I want "it wasn't funny bro" text to show up when I click to the emoji. When I click to the emoji it changes, but the text does not show up. I followed the same steps, it works for emojis but doesn't work for text. I could not figure out why it's not working.
My code looks like this:

```js
const beginningFace = document.querySelector(".beginning");
const reactionFace = document.querySelector(".reaction");

const beginningText = document.querySelector(".beginningT");
const reactionTextFirst = document.querySelector(".reactionT-first");
const reactionTextSecond = document.querySelector(".reactionT-second");


beginningFace.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    if(reactionFace.classList.contains('reaction')){
        reactionFace.classList.add('active');
        beginningFace.classList.remove('active');
        
    }

});

beginningText.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(reactionTextFirst.classList.contains('reactionT-first') && reactionTextSecond.classList.contains('reactionT-second')){
        reactionTextFirst.classList.add('active');
        reactionTextSecond.classList.add('active');
        beginningFace.classList.remove('active');
    }



});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+Dafoe&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:wght@900&display=swap');

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #202076;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  perspective: 700px;
  
}

.beginningT {
  display: none;
}

.reactionT-first {
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Exo';
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

.reactionT-second{
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Mr Dafoe';
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  margin-top: -0.6em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #fff, 0 0 0.2em #fe05e1, 0 0 0.3em #fe05e1;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.emoji{
    font-size: 18rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    
}


.beginning{
    display: none;
} 

.reaction{
    display: none;
}

.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    

    <div class="emoji beginning active"></div>
    <div class="emoji reaction"></div>
    
    <div class ="text beginningT active" style="font-size: 2rem; font-style: italic; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: #F98299;">My reaction after your joke↑ (click to see it!)</div>
    <div class="text reactionT-first">IT WASN'T</div>
    <div class="text reactionT-second">FUNNY BRO</div>

  




    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your other text to show up when you click on the emoji, you have to do all the logic inside `beginningFace.addEventListener`, instead of using two diffent event listeners. I moved the logic, and removed the second click listener.

These lines were missing in the first click listener

```
    reactionTextFirst.classList.add('active');
    reactionTextSecond.classList.add('active');
    beginningText.classList.remove('active');
```

```js
const beginningFace = document.querySelector(".beginning");
const reactionFace = document.querySelector(".reaction");

const beginningText = document.querySelector(".beginningT");
const reactionTextFirst = document.querySelector(".reactionT-first");
const reactionTextSecond = document.querySelector(".reactionT-second");


beginningFace.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    if(reactionFace.classList.contains('reaction')){
        reactionFace.classList.add('active');
        beginningFace.classList.remove('active');

        reactionTextFirst.classList.add('active');
        reactionTextSecond.classList.add('active');
        beginningText.classList.remove('active');
    }

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+Dafoe&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:wght@900&display=swap');

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #202076;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  perspective: 700px;
  
}

.beginningT {
  display: none;
}

.reactionT-first {
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Exo';
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 0;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

.reactionT-second{
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Mr Dafoe';
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  margin-top: -0.6em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #fff, 0 0 0.2em #fe05e1, 0 0 0.3em #fe05e1;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

.emoji{
    font-size: 18rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    
}


.beginning{
    display: none;
} 

.reaction{
    display: none;
}

.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    

    <div class="emoji beginning active"></div>
    <div class="emoji reaction"></div>
    
    <div class ="text beginningT active" style="font-size: 2rem; font-style: italic; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: #F98299;">My reaction after your joke↑ (click to see it!)</div>
    <div class="text reactionT-first">IT WASN'T</div>
    <div class="text reactionT-second">FUNNY BRO</div>

  




    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now I understand it thank you so much!